# Best way to model Cash, Credit Card transactions in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have one table called "transactions" but with different classes (CashTransaction and CreditCardTransaction) with a "type" column determining what row is what.

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Add a TransactionType table with a PK that corresponds to a FK of the selected type in your Transactions table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use STI if both of transaction type are having same attributes(table columns), create three models like

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord
    # create table called transactions and add type column to it.  
    # add common methods inside this class
end

class CashTransaction < Transaction
     # the type column will be CashTransaction and used to determine entry for this class in transactions table 
end

class CreditCardTransaction < Transaction    
    # the type column will be CreditCardTransaction and used to determine entry for this class in  transactions table 
end
```

and then you can create these transaction using child class

```
CreditCardTransaction.new 
CreditCardTransaction.find 
 #..etc
 # or 
CashTransaction.new
CashTransaction.find ..
```